# Is Laravel really this slow?

Tags: performance, laravel

I just started using Laravel. I've barely written any code yet, but my pages are taking nearly a second to load!

[image: laravel timings]

This is a bit shocking to me when my framework-less apps and NodeJS apps take ~2ms. What's Laravel doing? This isn't normal behaviour is it? Does it need some fine-tuning?

Comment: Try running `php artisan optimize --force`

Comment: @JosephSilber Thanks. That might have helped a bit. It's now flopping between ~110ms and ~580ms, nothing inbetween. Not sure what's causing the inconsistent behaviour. Regardless, even 110 is high IMO.

Comment: To be fair, the load times you're seeing are in the debugging mode. The debugbar you're using slows the application down quite a bit.

Comment: What does your environment look like? I see faster speeds on a VPS compared to me developing locally on a VM.

Comment: @kreeves I'm running Laravel through Vagrant on precise32, using the built-in PHP server. I'll try Nginx+HHVM and disable all the debugging later.

Comment: HHVM will do wonders, especially if you're not currently using opcache.

Comment: @Artsemis Just installed everything. It's more than twice as *slow*, and it's crashing after several refreshes.

Comment: @Mark Are you on Windows or Mac? VirtualBox or VMWare? Using Shared folders? I've heard some people bemoan the speed of shared folders in certain combinations of environments. I can't say I've seen them myself. I'm on OSX 10.7 using precise64+vagrant. I see around 200ms response times locally but MUCH faster on VPS hardware (Linode/DigitalOcean).

Comment: @kreeves: Yeah, I'm on Windows using precise64+vagrant. Didn't know shared folders were slow. I guess I won't find out how slow it really is until I deploy then :\

Comment: Yeah don't hope for anything fast using Vagrant. A Symfony page generally take like 1-2s to load in Vagrant, while it takes 50ms in production.

Comment: I suggest looking into Rsync for shared folders under windows.  I was recently using rails with vagrant, and it improved performance by like 500% no joke. Read/writes are just reallly slow because the file systems are different.

Comment: @Roeland If you look at my answer below, I mention rsync. It boosted me by *over* 2500%.

Comment: Our site runs under Apache.  I enabled Memcached and our site is lightning fast, as if it were NGINX!  Change your caching to Redis, Memcached or whatever else they offer.

Comment: This is why I switched to Laragon a couple months ago. Vagrant is so slow.

Comment: Generic frameworks are inerently slow, as they are generic and have to anticipate a wide variaty of use cases at it. If performance is an issue and I mean really an issue that cannot be solved with faster hardware or optimizations, write a framework specific for your needs. Having said that. PHP profileing with xdebug might point you in the direction where performance hits are felt the most.

Comment: My solution to this was to run everything in Docker. Problem is volume mapping from host in Windows is incredible slow and and has the same issue. If you run Docker with WSL though and store all your files in WSL the webserver is sooo much faster. PHPStorm also has built in support for WSL and works pretty good. All the developers I work with now dropped virtualbox for the docker setup. Also nice because we will soon be using the same container in prod so all our environments match.

Answer (score 105, accepted):

Laravel is **not** actually *that* slow. 500-1000ms is absurd; I got it down to 20ms in debug mode.

The problem was Vagrant/VirtualBox + shared folders. I didn't realize they incurred such a performance hit. I guess because Laravel has so many dependencies (loads ~280 files) and each of those file reads is slow, it adds up really quick.

kreeves pointed me in the right direction, [this blog post](https://servercheck.in/blog/rsync-vagrant-15-file-performance-windows-dev) describes a new feature in Vagrant 1.5 that lets you rsync your files into the VM rather than using a shared folder.

There's no native rsync client on Windows, so you'll have to use [cygwin](http://cygwin.com/install.html). Install it, and make sure to check off Net/rsync. Add `C:\cygwin64\bin` to your paths. [Or you can install it on Win10/Bash]

[Vagrant introduces the new feature](https://www.vagrantup.com/blog/feature-preview-vagrant-1-5-rsync.html). I'm using Puphet, so my Vagrantfile looks a bit funny. I had to tweak it to look like this:

```
  data['vm']['synced_folder'].each do |i, folder|
    if folder['source'] != '' && folder['target'] != '' && folder['id'] != ''
      config.vm.synced_folder "#{folder['source']}", "#{folder['target']}", 
        id: "#{folder['id']}", 
        type: "rsync",
        rsync__auto: "true",
        rsync__exclude: ".hg/"
    end
  end
```

Once you're all set up, try `vagrant up`. If everything goes smoothly your machine should boot up and it should copy all the files over. You'll need to run `vagrant rsync-auto` in a terminal to keep the files up to date. You'll pay a little bit in latency, but for 30x faster page loads, it's worth it!

---

If you're using PhpStorm, it's auto-upload feature works even better than rsync. PhpStorm creates a lot of temporary files which can trip up file watchers, but if you let it handle the uploads itself, it works nicely.

---

One more option is to use [lsyncd](https://github.com/axkibe/lsyncd). I've had great success using this on Ubuntu host -> FreeBSD guest. I haven't tried it on a Windows host yet.

---

I now use Docker + [DevSpace](https://devspace.sh/). DevSpace has a sync feature that is 1000x faster than Docker's mounted directories.

Comment: What did you to do to get your performance improved (aside from using rsync)?

Comment: @jpcamara Nothing. Rsync alone got it down to ~20ms. You can run it under HHVM, turn off any debugging and run `artisan optimize` for a slight boost. The rest is mostly how you design your app I think. Install `barryvdh/laravel-debugbar` and look for any slowness.

Comment: How does it load 280 files in 20ms? Some kind of compilation / OPcache used here? Assuming SSD storage, ofc.

Comment: @ManuelArwedSchmidt I didn't add any caching. I barely tuned anything at all. Computers as fast these days. They're small files. I have an SSD, but this is running off my HDD. Edit: Actually, Laravel does 'compile' a bunch of different files together by default. I don't remember if this was 280 + that magic file or not.

Comment: According to Taylor Otwell Laravel 5.2 will be even 25% faster: https://twitter.com/taylorotwell/status/674327734252892161

Comment: [lsyncd](https://github.com/axkibe/lsyncd) works well on linux/bsd for keeping your vagrant box up to date.

Comment: Use NFS file sharing instead of the default one. Speeds everything up 10 times... Modify your Vagrant file to force mount filesystem as NFS: config.vm.synced_folder ".", "/vagrant", type: "nfs", nfs: true, nfs_udp: false, nfs_version: 3

Comment: I'm not sure if this really proves if it's slow or not. You got some rps metric compared to other?

Comment: @ArnaldoCapo Didn't say it wasn't slow, just said it wasn't *that* slow. No, I don't have any RPS metrics. It runs fast enough for my needs, but I will still be switching away as soon as I can.

Answer (score 30):

To help you with your problem I found this [blog](http://lutro.priv.no/posts/optimizing-for-production-with-laravel-4) which talks about making laravel production optimized. Most of what you need to do to make your app fast would now be in the hands of how efficient your code is, your network capacity, CDN, caching, database.

*Now I will talk about the issue:*

Laravel is slow out of the box. There are ways to optimize it. You also have the option of using caching in your code, improving your server machine, yadda yadda yadda. But in the end Laravel is still slow.

Laravel uses a lot of symfony libraries and as you can see in [techempower's benchmarks](http://www.techempower.com/benchmarks/), symfony ranks very low (last to say the least). You can even find the laravel [benchmark](http://www.techempower.com/benchmarks/#section=data-r8&hw=i7&test=fortune) to be almost at the bottom.

A lot of auto-loading is happening in the background, things you might not even need gets loaded. So technically because laravel is easy to use, it helps you build apps fast, it also makes it slow.

But I am not saying Laravel is bad, it is **great**, great at a lot of things. But if you expect a high surge of traffic you will need a lot more hardware just to handle the requests. It would cost you a lot more. But if you are filthy rich then you can achieve anything with Laravel. :D

The usual trade-off:

```
 Easy = Slow, Hard = Fast
```

I would consider C or Java to have a hard learning curve and a hard maintainability but it ranks very high in web frameworks.

*Though not too related. I'm just trying to prove the point of `easy = slow`:*

Ruby has a very good reputation in maintainability and the easiness to learn it but it is also considered to be the slowest among python and php as shown [here](https://www.udemy.com/blog/modern-language-wars/).

Comment: what those graphics has to do with question ?

Comment: PHP7 is a lot faster than PHP5

Comment: What point? Easy = slow just further spreads unfounded misunderstanding towards particular languages

Comment: in infographics one error is that Pyhon can not be influenced by Java because java was invented in 1995 and python in 1991.

Comment: @HaritsinhGohil Python 3 was released on 2008.

Comment: @majidarif, that's ok if python3 influenced by some java features but i thought that you are talking about at the time of invention of python.

Comment: Showing those images i thought I am on instagram :-D

Answer (score 19):

Yes - Laravel IS really that slow. I built a POC app for this sake. Simple router, with a login form. I could only get **60 RPS** with 10 concurrent connections on a $20 digital ocean server (few GB ram);

Setup:

```
2gb RAM
Php7.0
apache2.4
mysql 5.7
memcached server (for laravel session)
```

I ran optimizations, composer dump autoload etc, and it actually **lowered the RPS to 43-ish**.

The problem is the app responds in 200-400ms. I ran AB test from the local machine laravel was on (ie, not through web traffic); and I got only 112 RPS; with 200ms faster response time with an average of 300ms.

Comparatively, I tested my production PHP Native app running a few million requests a day on a AWS t2.medium (x3, load balanced). When I AB'd 25 concurrent connections from my local machine to that over web, through ELB, I got roughly 1200 RPS. Huge difference on a machine with load vs a laravel "login" page.

These are pages with Sessions (elasticache / memcached), Live DB lookups (cached queries via memcached), Assets pulled over CDNs, etc, etc, etc.

What I can tell, laravel sticks about 200-300ms load over things. Its fine for PHP Generated views, after all, that type of delay is tolerable on load. However, for PHP views that use Ajax/JS to handle small updates, it begins to feel sluggish.

I cant imagine what this system would look like with a multi tenant app while 200 bots crawl 100 pages each all at the same time.

Laravel is great for simple apps. Lumen is tolerable if you dont need to do anything fancy that would require middleware nonsense (IE, no multi tenant apps and custom domains, etc);

However, I never like starting with something that can bind and cause 300ms load for a "hello world" post.

If youre thinking "Who cares?"

.. Write a predictive search that relies on quick queries to respond to autocomplete suggestions across a few hundred thousand results. That 200-300ms lag will drive your users absolutely insane.

Comment: Why is middleware nonsense? Care to explain with facts so that all of us can assert it's nonsense? Also, I run a Laravel installation that happily responds between 80 and 65 ms (yes, it performs a db query on a 4 billion record table) so I'm keen to see what you're on about.

Comment: You obviously love laravel. I setup a base install, optimized, and received poor results. I found it to require middleware and reverse engineering to handle pre route processing; which was not ideal.

Just because you got "YOUR" laravel install to optimize, great. Its irrelevant. A base package routing HELLO WORLD was way heavier and slower than a simple routing framework and a twig templating engine.

Can both be cached? Optimized? Improved? Yes. Is that the point? No. Laravel is heavy. Heavy is slow(er). The world agrees on that. use it if you like it, but this is not theology. :)

Comment: I love spending less time. I don't really care about a framework / technology / whatever, I'll assume you're the same. Less time spent to achieve a goal = that's a win in my book. Now, yes, Laravel is heavy. Every framework is heavy compared to bare-bones language. As any program / software - Laravel *can* run fast, which is the point of my comment. If a framework helps you, if you need to make it run quicker - that's achievable.

Comment: You are comparing a non-configured/optimized/cached instance of Laravel running on a $20 D.O. server to a custom build, highly tuned/optimized/cached php app, running on a $400 highly tuned/optimized/cached server infrastructure, then complaining that the un-optimized app is slow? Don't get me wrong, ALL frameworks are slow out of the box! There is no way to tune a framework to work for everyone. Plus, most frameworks are setup for a dev environment FIRST. Slow autoloading, non cached templates, etc. Please compare an apple to an apple, not an apple to a Ferrari, or in this case, a Zonda...

Comment: CodeIgniter is not slow out of the box. In fact, CodeIgniter is almost as fast as PHP itself. PHP = 300 rps, CodeIgniter = 295. Laravel is way below that. Zend is around 30 rps, and cake, from what I remember, a whopping 3 rps. No two frameworks are created equal. There's a few apples to look at. However, optimizing Laravel might give you 60 ms loads, imagine what optimizing CodeIgniter would get you. ;)

Comment: @jacobfogg no. the hardward was apples to apples, Apache php.info responded similarly.

And, Laravel was optimized. Lets face it. What moves faster? A single Knife, or a Toolbox? Its a simple term, but one I think you will understand more L

Comment: @Nick You post mentions: Laravel on a $20 DO server vs Native PHP on AWS t2.medium (x3, load balanced)... Please let me know if I misunderstood. I agree with your Knife vs Toolbox analogy, it's a good one! Like everything in our world, you need to use the right tools for the right job. I would never remodel my house to include a chef's kitchen if I just wanted a PBJ, but if I am opening a restaurant, nothing but a commercial kitchen will do. The types of projects I currently work on require, in your words, a full sized toolbox... But I've optimize server and code, and am happy with the speed!

Comment: PS. reading over the post one more time, there's also the statement: "These are pages with Sessions (elasticache / memcached), Live DB lookups (cached queries via memcached), Assets pulled over CDNs, etc, etc, etc." ... As I said, highly tuned to your specific use case. I believe, and I intend to test my belief, if you gave the same configuration and tuning attention to a laravel app, you'd end up with similar results. I'll post back to this thread once I am able to test my theory.

Comment: They are not tuned, They merely connect, and look at basic memcache nodes, etc. 

Laravel does the same out of the package.

I have received much hate out of my answer, but its still true. Ironically, I am making an app in laravel now even knowing its slow. You cant get fast out of laravel, blackfire / newrelic it. 

It uses too much memory on a single connection. However, servers are cheaper than time. If you are only dealing with 1k visitors engaging heavily a day, the $5 server difference wont matter ;)

Answer (score 15):

I found that biggest speed gain with Laravel 4 you can achieve choosing right session drivers;

```
Sessions "driver" file;

Requests per second:    188.07 [#/sec] (mean)
Time per request:       26.586 [ms] (mean)
Time per request:       5.317 [ms] (mean, across all concurrent requests)


Session "driver" database;

Requests per second:    41.12 [#/sec] (mean)
Time per request:       121.604 [ms] (mean)
Time per request:       24.321 [ms] (mean, across all concurrent requests)
```

Hope that helps

Comment: Obvious and i'd recommend to anyone to never use file as a session. Think of scalability :)

Comment: @jeveloper what? In this example, file is over 4 times faster than database

Comment: @Brett "think of scalability" was the point, sure file vs network calls to possibly remote machine (even if its within the same VPC) would be slower but at least its sustainable and you capture session data

Comment: @jeveloper is the filesystem not sustainable? I sure hope it is, since that is the underlying storage for most databases anyway.

Comment: @developerbmw What he's trying to say is if you have a loadbalancer and mulitple instances serving your application, using the file system of the local server is not scalable.

Comment: Did 4 not support memcached?  Session should not point to file or db if you can do memcached

Comment: How about Redis? What does the performance look like for Redis as a session driver? Redis is what real programmers are using.

Comment: MEMCACHED was used for my test (one of the answers) and it was still crap.

Answer (score 11):

From my Hello World contest, Which one is Laravel? I think you can guess.
I used docker container for the test and
here is the results

To make http-response "Hello World":

- Golang with log handler stdout : 6000 rps
- SpringBoot with Log Handler stdout: 3600 rps
- Laravel 5 with off log :230 rps

Comment: Don't know why this has been marked own, yes maybe more appropriate as a comment. Although I also experience EXTREMELY slow response times within a docker container ~600ms

Comment: did you try route caching ?

Comment: what is rps? requests per second?

Comment: Hello world is the best and most useful application ever, especially when used for meaningful tests. It totally covers everything you need to know, from which component is used to package / package manager support for a language.

Comment: I just want performance baseline w/o other complicated dependency

Answer (score 4):

I use Laravel quite a bit and I simply do not believe the numbers it tells me because end-to-end rendering as measured by my browser shows LOWER total time from request to ready.

Further, I get slightly higher numbers on my machine at work, which does execute the page noticeably faster than my machine at home.

I don't know how those numbers are getting calculated, but they are not corroborated by observation, or browser tools like Firebug...

Laravel is not actually all that slow, especially when optimized. It is memory-hungry however. Even a heavy CMS like Drupal which is very slow, appears to have about 1/3rd the memory footprint of a bare bones Laravel request.

Thus to run Laravel in production, I would deploy to memory-optimized servers before CPU-optimized servers.

Comment: I'm not sure if those numbers are spot on but it's *definitely* noticeable. What do you mean by "especially when optimized"? How are you optimizing it? Just by running `php artisan optimize` or is there more we can do?

Comment: Couple of things you can do are outlined in these two links:

http://crynobone.com/posts/7/crunching-laravel-4-for-production-server | http://lutro.priv.no/posts/optimizing-for-production-with-laravel-4

Answer (score 4):

I know this is a little old question, but things changed. Laravel isn't that slow. It's, as mentioned, synced folders are slow. However, on Windows 10 I wasn't able to use `rsync`. I tried both `cygwin` and `minGW`. It seems like `rsync` is incompatible with `git for windows`'s version of `ssh`.

Here is what worked for me: **NFS**.

[Vagrant docs](https://www.vagrantup.com/docs/synced-folders/nfs.html) says:

> NFS folders do not work on Windows hosts. Vagrant will ignore your request for NFS synced folders on Windows.

This isn't true anymore. We can use `vagrant-winnfsd` [plugin](https://github.com/winnfsd/vagrant-winnfsd) nowadays. It's really simple to install:

1. Execute `vagrant plugin install vagrant-winnfsd`
2. Change in your `Vagrantfile`: `config.vm.synced_folder ".", "/vagrant", type: "nfs"`
3. Add to `Vagrantfile`: `config.vm.network "private_network", type: "dhcp"`

That's all I needed to make `NFS` work. Laravel response time decreased from 500ms to 100ms for me.

Comment: Did you try rsync via Bash for Windows? I'm running it right now actually, and it works great.

Comment: No, I didn't try it. I know, many people writes that rsync works great with git bash too or windows cmd. I don't know why it's not working for me. But I found another solution anyway. Maybe it would be useful for someone.

Answer (score 4):

Since nobody else has mentioned it, I found that the xdebug debugger dramatically increased the time. I served a basic "Hello World, the time is 2020-01-01T01:01:01.010101" dynamic page and used this in my httpd.conf to time the request:

```
LogFormat "%h %l %u %t \"%r\" %>s %b \"%{Referer}i\" \"%{User-Agent}i\" **%T/%D**" combined
```

%T is the serve time in seconds, %D is the time in microseconds. With this in my php.ini:

```
[XDebug]
xdebug.remote_autostart = 1
xdebug.remote_enable = 1
```

I was getting around 770ms response times, but with both of those set to 0 to disable them, it jumped to 160ms instantly. Running both of these brought it down to 120ms:

```
php artisan route:cache
php artisan config:cache
```

The downside being that if I made config or route changes, I would need to re-cache them, which is annoying.

As a sidenote, oddly, moving the site from my SSD to a spinning HDD provided no performance benefits, which is super odd to me, but I suppose it's maybe cached, I'm on Windows 10 with XAMPP.

Comment: Some good benchmarks and advice, but why do you think that moving from an SSD to a HDD would make things faster? Also, note that you can use `php artisan optimize` in production to run all Laravel's caching operations, and `php artisan optimize:clear` to clear all of them. Generally I believe the idea is to run the latter in production, and the former when developing/debugging.

Comment: I didn't expect it to make things faster. I expected my HDD to be slower, and was surprised when it wasn't. My guess as to why, is that the HDD files were actually cached in RAM, and so when they were read, it didn't actually use the disk at all, so SSD vs HDD didn't matter. That's a guess though.

Comment: I hope newcomers pay attention to this part "The downside being that if I made config or route changes, I would need to re-cache them, which is annoying."

Answer (score 2):

I faced `1.40s` while working with a pure laravel in development area!

the problem was using: `php artisan serve` to run the webserver

when I used apache webserver (or NGINX) instead for the same code I got it down to `153ms`

Comment: yes about 140 is a minimum I could get, still slow as hell, symfony being bloated still much faster

Answer (score 2):

Came across this while troubleshooting slow load times +300ms booting Laravel 9. Found disabling xdebug and reloading apache and php-fpm reduced time to 20ms. Had xdebug enabled in dev... would not have been enabled in prod, but had to be certain of the performance.

Answer (score 0):

I don't have any benchmarks to hand, but it's well established that caching can help speeds significantly and Laravel has at least four different types of caches for different assets. The `php artisan optimize` command can be used to trigger all of these caching operations, with `php artisan optimize:clear` doing the opposite and invalidating all caches.

Generally I believe the idea is to run the latter when developing/debugging, to stop cached data from getting in your way, and to run the latter on a live site as soon as you've stopped developing/debugging it for the day.