# How to make laravel to faster page loading than codeigniter

Tags: codeigniter, laravel, laravel-5.1, codeigniter-3

I am new to `laravel` It's good for coding but it is not much faster than `codeigniter`

I have worked with `codeigniter` it's page loading is less then 5MB but `laravel` page loading is probably same to 8MB. i want to work with `laravel` but i need suggestion to make `laravel` faster then `codeigniter`

Comment: Codeigniter is a framework with small footprint and it is pointed to small/medium projects. Laravel instead, has more powerful services, providers and tools that make it pointed to medium and large projects.

Comment: Laravel is not a faster framework. If you want faster and advance MVC, then use Yii2.
But you can still load pages faster by enabling cache in Laravel.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You have many options to speed up your app :

> 1- run : php artisan optimize
>
> 2- disable the debugger
>
> 3- disable the services you don`t use in config.app file
>
> 4- if you are using homestead or vagrantBox this adds some shared
> folders that slows up the process.
>
> 5- if you are working in small,medium size project you can use lumen(lightweight version of laravel).
>
> 6-Cache your routes by running : php artisan route:cache
>
> 7-Cache your config by running : php artisan config:cache

Some other general tips -relevant to laravel- :

> 1-If you have data that is frequently fetched for example latest articles in a blog or top scores on a list try implementing a caching layer this would enhance your app performance drastically
>
> 2-Queues / back ground jobs , are very useful if you have some processes that take time and could be run in the background for example sending an email, crawling the web

and check out those resources :

https://laracasts.com/discuss/channels/general-discussion/laravel-optimizations-or-speed-ups

http://ionut-bajescu.com/posts/view/improving-your-laravel-application-performance

[Is Laravel really this slow?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23283574/is-laravel-really-this-slow)

https://mattstauffer.co/blog/laravel-5.0-route-caching

Comment: Avoid lumen if you wish to spend your time coding than debugging. Just spent 4 hours trying to debug packages that refuse to support lumen and finally i threw the towel and went with laravel instead. Reference: https://laravel-news.com/jwt-authentication-for-lumen