# Long loading times for laravel webserver

Tags: laravel, laravel-5

When creating a new laravel project using `composer create-project`, using the latest version of laravel (currently 5.6), I have really long loading times.

I'm using the `php artisan serve` to boot up my web server. When going to a browser, the page can take from 900 to 1200ms to load.

I'm using PHP 7.2.5.

[image]

From [my research](https://stackoverflow.com/q/23283574/2989034) I found out that 500-1000ms is really long. What could be causing this and how can I fix this? I've written no code.

Comment: I've updated my question. Using 7.2.5 and those 2 options aren't defined in my ini file

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are a number of bottlenecks which can apply to a Laravel project, and add latency. 
Lets rule some out first :

- ping time to hosting server (not relevant, you are using localhost)
- Eloquent database queries can easily take 1000ms+ (not relevant, welcome page does not use database queries)
- Media (not relevant, your screenshot clearly shows the problem is XHR (green)
- XHR : The transfer of data between a web-browser and a web server. Ergo, the problem is your server environment

**Quick fix - install MAMP or WAMP and run your dev environment through that.**

Longer fix - optimise your system for hosting. Without knowing your computer setup its hard to know where to begin. Assuming you are using a fast mac machine, first check your php version :

```
which php
```

This should report the same version of php that you installed, 7.2.5. If it doesn't that could be a problem and you need to set that version of php. the command for doing this looks similar to the following:

```
$ brew unlink php55
$ brew install php70
```

next - look for rogue extensions. IMAP is one possible culprit. Try this:

```
time php -n -d extension=imap.so -v
```

It should report a ping of under 0.5 seconds. If not you will need to disable IMAP extension. You can disable it by commenting out the imap extension :

```
vi /usr/local/php5/php.d/50-extension-imap.ini
;extension=imap.so
```

I recommend the quick fix ;)