# speed up Laravel project

Tags: laravel, laravel-8

Here we have a big laravel project and heavy database.
Problem is execution time. sometimes refresh page without network issue take 8 seconds.

For speed test I create a simple Route that print `Hello world` and nothing else, this route take `700ms` on server.

server OS : ubunto 18.04,
Laravel : 8,
Webserver : nginx,

i do these :

- run `composer dumpautoload -o`
- `php artisan optimize`
- cached routes
- cached config

Comment: There are many factors that define the site speed, and yes what you already did helps with the site speed. On top of mind here's are the factors 1. Server specs and configuration; 2. How you build the site, like are you running a bunch of SQL queries on all the pages.

Comment: Maybe this can help you: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23283574/is-laravel-really-this-slow

Comment: @aceraven777 my code is on linux server. this question helped to windows users.

Comment: Are you using a mysql database? What is a heavy database? Sounds like you need to optimize your queries. Avoid subqueries for example. If it is really a huge database, maybe a PostgreSQL database would be better, especially when you've got some complex queries.

Comment: no i meant to say `heavy database`, heavy data(big data). about 3 GB.
but problem is about laravel no database I think

Comment: Use laravel debugbar and check slow queries in project. Than optimize.

Comment: @Sahandi81 I don't think Laravel itself is the problem. Slow queries, foreach and nested foreach can be. But thats hard to see with this info. Do you use Eloquent? Db facade? Raw queries? If you install the laravel debugbar, you can find out the speed of the queries: https://github.com/barryvdh/laravel-debugbar

Comment: guys i said created a simple route that JUST print `speed test` and this take 700ms every time I refresh the page. https://api.digiattar.com/api/speed-test here you can see it

Comment: @Sahandi81 from the 8 seconds the 700ms isn't the issue, me thinks. Lets say that by reducing the middleware and optimizing cache you can get to 400ms. That will not solve your speed issue.